# What's a good range of weights to evaluate for $L_2$ regularized logistic regression?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, regularization

I want to find a weight that minimizes an averaged cross validated misclassification score from an $L_2$ logistic regression classifier. Obviously, the search space for the weights should be bounded below by zero, but are there any other rules of thumb for selecting weights to test? Should I search in the log space?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by selecting the weight? Do you mean, for example, you're optimizing a penalized likelihood $$ L(\beta) + \lambda Q(\beta) $$ where $\beta$ are the parameters, $L$ is the log-likelihood and $Q$ is the $L_2$ penalty and you're asking how to choose $\lambda$?

Comment: That's exactly right.